# Web Java applet show web page

Tags: java, applet, browser

Is it possible to make an web Java applet that loads a web page? I need to load an web page inside a web page.

An iframe, object and other HTML things I don't need. I need just a Java applet.

Some source code or tutorials?

Comment: It's possible, may I ask why?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.
Swing text components support HTML ([EditorPanes at Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)) but if the web page is too complex it might not be displayed correctly.